# Severity: Warning Message: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given Filename: controllers/main.php Line Number: 676

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

When I run this function, I'm getting

> Message: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given  in line number 676
>   Severity: Warning  Message: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given  Filename: controllers/main.php  Line Number: 676

```
function get_order_details()
{

  $query1="SELECT * FROM order_main ";
  $o_main=$this->main_model->query_return($query1); 

  $query="SELECT * FROM order_main om join order_details od on od.order_main_id=om.order_id ";
  $o_details=$this->main_model->query_return($query);   

  if(count($o_details))
  {

    $ary = array(
      'details'=> array(
        'orders'=>array()
      )
    );

    foreach($o_main as $om)
    {
      $jsonCustomer=array(
        $om->order_id=> array(
          array("order_id"=>$om->order_id,
            "customer_name"=>$om->customer_name,
            "contact_no"=>$om->contact_no,
            "address"=>$om->address,
            "landmark"=>$om->landmark,
            "items"=>array()
          )
        )
      );

      array_push($ary['details']['orders'],$jsonCustomer);
      foreach($o_details as $od)
      {
        $jsonRow=array(
          $od->dish_id=> array(
            "dish_id"=>$od->dish_id,
            "dishname"=>$od->dish_name,
            "qty"=>$od->qty,
            "category_id"=>$od->category_id,
            "category_name"=>$od->category_name,
            "price"=>$od->price,
          )
        );

        array_push($ary['details']['orders'][$om->order_id]   ['items'],$jsonRow);  

      }

    }

  echo $json=json_encode($ary);

  }

}
```

Comment: Because array `$ary['details']['orders']` is empty

Comment: Thanks, and how to fix this

Comment: `$jsonCustomer` is initialized with a double array for `$om->order_id` instead of a single one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is this line fails:

`array_push($ary['details']['orders'][$om->order_id]   ['items'],$jsonRow);`

Seen you initialize $jsonCustomer with a double array for `$om->order_id` instead of a single one.

Secondly, because you push an array into an array, another double array occurs instead of (what you want) have the index of `$om->order_id`

Change:

```
 $jsonCustomer=array(
    $om->order_id=> array(
      array("order_id"=>$om->order_id,
        "customer_name"=>$om->customer_name,
        "contact_no"=>$om->contact_no,
        "address"=>$om->address,
        "landmark"=>$om->landmark,
        "items"=>array()
      )
    )
  );

  array_push($ary['details']['orders'],$jsonCustomer);
```

Into

```
$jsonCustomer=array(
    "order_id"=>$om->order_id,
    "customer_name"=>$om->customer_name,
    "contact_no"=>$om->contact_no,
    "address"=>$om->address,
    "landmark"=>$om->landmark,
    "items"=>array()
);
$ary['details']['orders'][$om->order_id] = $jsonCustomer;
```

And the code should run.

Comment: thanks for your reply ,and as you expected the error is in this line only array_push($ary['details']['orders'][$om->order_id]   ['items'],$jsonRow); but i changed into your code,still getting same error

Comment: Yes, it gives an error because `$ary['details']['orders'][$om->order_id] ['items']` does not exist due to the initialisation of the jsonCustomer. You defined it as: `$ary['details']['orders'][$om->order_id][0]['items']`

Comment: i tried it also,but no use getting same error Message: array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in line  array_push($ary['details']['orders'][$om->order_id][0]['items'],$jsonRow);

Comment: Both changes wont work off course, Just changing the initialization for jsoncustomer should be enough

Comment: how to initializing the jsoncustomer?

Comment: Did you do the modification as proposed in the answer (just that, nothing from the comments), and that does not run?

Comment: now error is not coming but not getting answer as expected,and thanks for this much of help

Answer (score 1):

Check with if condition for $ary['details']['orders'] value is empty or not.

Comment: no its not empty,its echoing the values when i print "print_r($ary['details']['orders'] );"

Comment: can you post sample output of 'print_r($ary['details']['orders'] );'?

Answer (score 0):

check this if empty or not

```
if(!empty($ary['details']['orders'])){
  $order_details = $ary['details']['orders'];
}else{
  $order_details = 'any default value';
}
```

Now use here or wherever you want

```
 array_push($order_details,$jsonCustomer);
```

You may use isset() if not use empty()